# how to remove the extra field returned by laravel 7.14?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I'm using laravel 7.14 ..

I have these columns below in my db table

- alien_group_id
- allow_add
- allow_edit
- allow_delete
- status

My model is like this

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AlienModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'alien_group';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $casts = [
        'menu' => 'array'
    ];


}
```

whenever I add a data , I call the "save()" function like this

```
$alienGroup = new AlienModel();
$alienGroup->allow_add = 1;
$alienGroup->allow_edit = 1;
$alienGroup->allow_delete = 0;
$alienGroup->status  = 1;

if ($alienGroup->save()) {
    return $alienGroup;
}
```

my problem now is, the return value is like this

```
[
'allow_add' => 1,
'allow_edit' => 1,
'allow_delete' => 0,
'status' => 1,
'id' => 1
]
```

I don't know where the "id" came from, I don't have that field in my db nor in my migration file.
why is laravel adding that "id" in the returned result?, I should be receiving a alien_group_id at the beginning of the returned array not an unknown "id" field appended at the end of the array

Comment: Please share your model for $alienGroup.

Comment: I have shared my model contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Primary Keys**

Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key column named id. You may define a protected $primaryKey property to override this convention:

```
class AlienModel extends Model
{
    /**
     * The primary key associated with the table.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'alien_group_id';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hidden variable in the model

```
class AlienMode extends Eloquent {

     protected $primaryKey = 'alien_group_id';
     protected $hidden = ['alien_group_id']

}
```

whatever field are you define in this array, you won't have those fields come through when accessing your Eloquent models.